# How to set Vi key bindings for man pages

Tags: command-line, configuration, manpage, less, pager

How can I set <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd> keys to go up and down in manpages?

In `less` the keys work, but for some reason, manpages have configured <kbd>J</kbd> to be used for *go to line*. So when I accidentally press <kbd>J</kbd>, I am always taken to the *go to line:* prompt.

Is there any way to disable it at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason. For some reason, my `PAGER` environment variable was set to `most`.

The following command did the trick:

```bash
cp /usr/share/doc/packages/most/lesskeys.rc ~/.mostrc
```

**Note:** I could have also mapped the `PAGER` variable to `less`, but `most` is colorful. :)

Comment: That edit is surprising .`less` and `most` should both work the same as far as highlighting is concerned, since it's `man` itself that sets the highlighting - the pagers simply render what's given.